# array merge by key value in php and in js

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, merge

I have this.

```
     array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
  }
    ["a"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "c"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "d"
  }
  ["b"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
  }
}
```

how can i merge both in php and js to return same array looks like:

```
array(2) {
  ["a"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
        [3]=>
    string(1) "d"
  }
    ["b"]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "a"
        [1]=>
        string(1) "b"
        [2]=>
        string(1) "c"
      }
    }
```

Comment: What are keys and what are values for the arrays? Can you note the arrays as PHP variables please so it's more clear?

Comment: http://php.net/array_merge_recursive  perhaps?

Comment: if i post on stack is for having some good piece of code from people with more experience then me, i think it's not constructive a guide link :/

Comment: Please give more detail, maybe a real example array... In your example you have 2 keys named "a", this should not happen and is a problem. It seems like its part of the problem you are trying to fix. I would suggest fixing the code that generates the erroneous array instead of trying to fix it after the fact

Comment: uhm i think you're right, i written manually the array, but it's not possible that script generates an array like the first one (not merged) ? :P maybe i'm going crazy and i need rest :/

Answer (score 2):

In php, you may use [array_merge_recursive](http://www.php.net/array_merge_recursive)

In Js, you don't have such thing native.
But you have a [array_merge_recursive](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_merge_recursive:327) version in js

Comment: cause maybe i din't understand but in php manual talks about 2 arrays, here i have 1 big array or i'm mistaking?

Comment: Ispuk, split up the array first then pass them to `array_merge_recursive` or just use `call_user_func_array`